# Why is this query not working from python to SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, valueerror

I am new to coding and databases, I can not get the query to work if I write it long hand but I have a lot to carry out and want it in a function but cannot get it to work, it returns a parameters error

```
import  mysql.connector

def connection_check_1(query, value):

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="******",
        user="*****",
        passwd="*****",
        database="****"
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(query, (value))
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    mydb.close()
    return myresult

value = "sheep"
query = 'select inlicence from licence where animal = %s'
myresult = connection_check_1(query, value)
print(myresult)
```

Here is the SQL table I have

```
create table licence 
(
    animal varchar (20) primary key,
    inlicence int (1)
);
```

This is the error I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "*******************", line 20, in 
>   myresult = connection_check_1(query, value)
>   File "********************", line 13, in connection_check_1
>   mycursor.execute(query, (value))
>   File "********************************************88", line 246, in execute
>   prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
>   File "/home/kev/PycharmProjects/test bed/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 535, in prepare_for_mysql
>   raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
>   ValueError: Could not process parameters

I have tried changing the way the query is written, changing it to `fetchall()`.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please report the exact error message you get, including all of any traceback.

Comment: have included the error message, I have tried to change the query to add a string instead of the place card.

Comment: yes sorry @Tony, I am very new to all this (coding and stack overflow), I appreciate your comment.

Comment: @KevinjohnHustings - No need to apologise, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping a value with `()` doesn't turn it in to a tuple.  You probably meant to add a comma there:

```
mycursor.execute(query, (value,))
# Creates a one-element tuple-^
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mureinik! Now everything works a treat, just a simple comma missing, I have been scratching my head for ages